# What is the kernel of a number?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, trace

tr: R^2×2 → R

trace \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}

Is a linear transformation.

What is ker(tr)?

I am confused with this question, how can I find the trace of a a real number. All the videos and material I see is finding the trace of a matrix.

Edit: As people have pointed out I meant to say find the kernel of a real number. Which is also inaccurate because I am finding the kernel of the transformation which is a matrix.

Comment: "how can I find the trace of a a real number" : this is not at all what you are asked to find. Not sure where the confusion is.

Comment: A number is an $1\times 1$ matrix. Also, to be precise, you do not compute the trace of a matrix, but of a linear application.

Comment: They're saying trace is a linear transformation that inputs 2x2 matrices with real number entries and outputs real numbers. The question is what's the kernel of this linear transformation.

Comment: @KyleMiller Yes I proved that trace(2x2) was a linear transformation in a previous problem. But, I guess I am confused how I go about finding the kernel of a linear transformation.

Comment: So is this just trying to get me to point out that ker(tr) is when a and d = 0?

Comment: I think you need to state your problem correctly before asking it so the problem-solution should be more obvious. You consider $\mathrm{tr}:\mathsf{Mat}(2\times2) \to \mathbf{R}$ the trace "operator" and you know this is linear. What you want is the kernel of this linear function. Now write the conditions for $\mathrm{tr}(A) = 0$ to be true. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: @WilliamM. This is the question verbatim from my worksheet. So basically as I said in my comments, for ker(tr)=0  a and d must be 0 correct?

Comment: I mean a=-d for ker(tr) = 0.

Comment: The kernel of a linear map is the set of inputs that yield the value $0$. So yes, the kernel of the trace is the set of $2\times2$ matrices such that $a=-d$.

Comment: @GregMartin Alright so that would make the dim(ker(tr))=2 therefore dim(im(tr))=0?

Comment: Neither of those dimension calculations is true—take some time and think about it again :)

Comment: @GregMartin Alright, well I orginally had that dim(ker(tr))= (a, -d) = 1 therefore dim(im(tr))=1 but I guess I am not sure.

Comment: There are 4 elements that make up a $2\times 2$ matrix, so you should expect the sum of the dimensions of kernel and image of your operator to be 4, not 2.

Comment: @Gregory Yes thank you I just realized that, a video from a UCLA student said "the dimension of the target space is 2 because you have a 2x2 matrix" which really threw me off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be groups and let $f$ be a homomorphism. The kernel of $f : A \longrightarrow B$ is the set

$$\ker f \enspace := \enspace \{ \, a \in A \, | \, f(a) = e_B \in B \, \} \quad ,$$

where $e_B$ is the neutral element of $B$.

${}$

**Example 1:**
If $A, B$ are vector spaces, then the neutral element is the zero vector. So $\ker f$ is the set of all vectors in $A$ which map to the zero vector $0_B$ in $B$.

**Example 2:**
Let $A = B = \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ be the set of $(2 \times 2)$-matrices and let the group operation be the matrix-multiplication. Then the neutral element of $B$ is the identity matrix and so the kernel is the set of all matrices $a \in A$ for which $f(a) = 1_{2\times2}$.

**Here:**
In your specific case $A = \mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ is the space of real $(2\times 2)$-matrices and $f = \operatorname{tr} : \mathbb{R}^{2\times2} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and so $B = \mathbb{R}$. The kernel of $\operatorname{tr}$ is therefore the set of all matrices which get mapped to the neutral element of $\mathbb{R}$, which is $0$.

So given a matrix of the form

$$a \enspace = \enspace \left[ \begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{matrix} \right]$$

the trace is

$$\operatorname{tr}(a) \enspace = \enspace a_{11} + a_{22} \quad .$$

In order for the trace to vanish, you must have $a_{11} = -a_{22}$, and so the kernel is the set

$$\ker \operatorname{tr} \enspace = \enspace \left\{ \;  \left[ \begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & -a_{11} \end{matrix} \right] \; \Bigg| \; a_{11}, a_{12}, a_{21} \in \mathbb{R} \; \right\} \quad .$$

As you can see, one can choose three components of the matrices in the kernel freely and so the dimension of the kernel is 3. This can also be seen by the rank-theorem

$$\underbrace{\dim A}_{= \, 4} \enspace = \enspace \underbrace{\dim \operatorname{im} \operatorname{tr}}_{= 1} + \dim \ker \operatorname{tr} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \dim \ker \operatorname{tr} \enspace = \enspace 3 \quad .$$

Comment: Thank you I would upvote your answer if I could but people downvoted my question because I was very confused when I asked it but it has now been made clear to me and edited. So, I don't have the karma to upvote your answer.